# How do I get Input to read other keys and not just Up and Down

Tags: c#, input, keycode

I saw some codes like this:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
```

and

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
```

Wanted to know how do I put other keys, as in the case of the "a"

```
 if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.AArrow))
```

tried this code here however it gives an error, as I write?

Comment: What is this "AArrow" key?

Comment: According to the docs you can do `GetKey(KeyCode.A))` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html

Answer (score 0):

When using KeyCode in comparison (like an `if` statement) you must call the specific keycode you want to compare the input to. Microsoft has [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) which provides the standard KeyCodes represented in `System.Windows` which most, if not all, external libraries call to.

So in this case you need to check for the `A` key specifically.

```
if (Input.GeyKey(KeyCode.A))
{
    //code runs if and only if the input key is the A key
}
else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
{
    //code runs if and only if the input key is the ESC key.
}
```

Now if you want many possible inputs at a specific time you may not wish to use an `if` statement, but I would recommend trying this out first to see if you get better results.

Comment: I understood you, thank you very much ;)